# Batch - Move File to Network Drive without being logged in

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following script which is setup as a task to automatically move a file to a mapped network drive. The problem is that this only works when a user is logged in and has an active Windows session open. However, if the user is logged off these backups wont happen as I believe it cannot find the network drive. This is running on a Windows 2003 Server. Is there anyway to alter the script to make sure it can connect to the networked drive while no active sessions are open?

The process I am using is to move the file, then delete the file to clear up hard-drive space, then a .exe is run to empty the recycling bin.

```
@echo off
move C:\StarshipBackup\*.* Z:\StarshipDataBackup
del C:\StarshipBackup\*.* /F /Q
C:\emptyrecycle.exe
```

Comment: A system account, which is the default task scheduler account, doesn't have access to network resources.  You can use the credentials of a user who does have network access.  As an aside, you might also like to enable generations of backups and use more than one backup hard drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mount the drive in the batch file.  Add this before your `move` command:

```
net use z: \\yourserver\sharename
```

Of course, you need to make sure that the account the batch file runs under has permission to access the share.  If you are doing this by using a Scheduled Task, you can choose the account by selecting the task, then:

- right click Properties
- click on General tab change account under
- "When running the task, use the following user account:"

That's on Windows 7, it might be slightly different on different versions of Windows.